# How to set web role to user logined by Google Oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, powerapps

https://srinathpega.com/2022/03/25/power-apps-portal-9-portal-authenticationoauth-2-0-with-gmail/
I have followed the above post, and the user can successfully login with google mail.
But I want to set permissions for that user using webrole.
I guess the users will be managed in the contacts table, but I don't see any google logged in users in the contacts table.

In powerpages, how to set webrole to user logined by google authentication.